# Looping through a table and changing formula

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a relatively small table (2-5 rows / 7-9 columns) that I'm trying to loop through and calculate values using .formula. I'm having some issues figuring out how I refer to the absolute values of the column or row of the cell that I'm on. Here's what I've hard-coded so far:

```
For i = 1 To Range("GapTable").Rows.Count
    For i2 = 2 To Range("GapTable").Columns.Count
        Range("GapTable").Cells(i, i2).Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(AVERAGEIFS(prof_gap, series, $A21, grade, B$20),2), ""N/A"")"
    Next i2
Next i
```

I'm trying to figure out how to change $A21 to lock the column in as an absolute, and B$20 to lock the row in, with the formula copying to the adjacent cells correctly (the same as if you took the cursor and filled in the values). The code works now, but obviously the values are all the same. Any suggestions how I address this issue, or a better way of doing this?

Comment: Paste over the range of cells, rather than to each individual cell.  That allows Excel to do its job and utilize the Fixed portions of the address.  No need to loop.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in my comment, you can paste over the range, where the dynamic references are to the upper left cell, e.g.,

```
with Range("GapTable")
    .range(.cells(1,2),.cells(.Rows.Count,.Columns.Count)).Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(AVERAGEIFS(prof_gap, series, $A21, grade, B$20),2), ""N/A"")"
end with
```

If you have to loop, you can use counters, e.g.:

```
dim colnum as long, rownum as long
For i = 1 To Range("GapTable").Rows.Count
    For i2 = 2 To Range("GapTable").Columns.Count
        Range("GapTable").Cells(i, i2).Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(AVERAGEIFS(prof_gap, series, $A" & rownum & ", grade, " & cells(20,colnum).address & "),2), ""N/A"")"
        colnum = colnum + 1
    Next i2
    rownum = rownum + 1
Next i
```

Note that you have to convert the column number to an address, which is why the `cell()` reference includes the `20`.

I did not include the error handling for resetting `rownum`/`colnum` to *reset* back to 20/2, respectively.  Just throwing out the concept if for some reason you can't just paste over the range.

---

**Edit1:** forgot the `.` in front of `cells(1,2)` in the `with`statement for pasting over a range.

Comment: Interesting. Your solution using 'With Range("GapTable") does work, but it fills in an additional 20 rows of formulas, even though I only have 2 rows originally in the table (excluding the header). Not sure why this is happening, the .rows.count returns 2 when I step through it.

Comment: I think I know why..... the Range(Cells1(1,2) part doesn't reference the first row, second column of my "GapTable", it's just Cell B1 on the sheet. Should this be happening with range("gaptable")?

Comment: @Sudio Sorry, that `.` should be before that `.cells()` reference.

Comment: Thanks @Cyril, tested and it works great. Thanks for the assist